# Taking a string and splitting it into an array of strings in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to take an array and split it into an array of strings, this is my code:

```
if split != "" {

    for i := 0; i < len(split); i++ {

        for j := 0; j < len(split); j += 0 {

            splits := []byte(split)

            if splits[i] == ' ' {


                result := split[i] - split[j]

                for k := 0; k <= i; k++ {

                    fitting := make([]byte, result)
                    fitting[k] = splits[k]
                    fmt.Println(fitting[k])

                    if k > i-1 {

                        fittings := string(fitting[:])
                        word := []string{}
                        words := append(word, fittings)
                        fmt.Println(split, words)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
return Strings(split)
```

and this is my test case:

```
fmt.Println(actual, expected)

for i := 0; i < len(expected); i++ {

    if actual[i] != expected[i] {
        t.Errorf("does not match")
        t.Fail()
    }

}
}
```

None of it is really working.

Comment: What is your actual problem? You have posted your code and your test, okay. What kind of help are you looking for? PS: it also would be ideal if you provided minimal yet complete examples which are possible to run on https://play.golang.org/ with little to no modifications.

Comment: Please provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). Furthermore, please specify the structure of your inputs (including an example, preferably) and the expected outputs. It is unclear to me from your question precisely what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just need to know how I could possibly take a string such as "hi li le" and make it into an array of strings such as ["hi","li","le"]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 7):

> *I just need to know how I could possibly take a string such as "hi li le" and make it into an array of strings such as ["hi","li","le"]*

Yes with [`strings.Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) or [`strings.Fields`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields).

```
for _, word := range strings.Fields("hi li le") {
    fmt.Println(word)
}
```

Here's a way to do it manually, for illustration.

```
func split(tosplit string, sep rune) []string {
    var fields []string

    last := 0
    for i,c := range tosplit {
        if c == sep {
            // Found the separator, append a slice
            fields = append(fields, string(tosplit[last:i]))
            last = i + 1
        } 
    }

    // Don't forget the last field
    fields = append(fields, string(tosplit[last:]))

    return fields
}

func main() {
    str := "hello world stuff"
    for _,field := range split(str, ' ') {
        fmt.Println(field)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to know how I could possibly take a string such as "hi li
> le" and make it into an array of strings such as ["hi","li","le"]

I would like to respond this with simple a simple example:

```
s := "hi li le"
arr := strings.Split(s, " ")
fmt.Println(arr)
```

Note: Make sure to import strings & fmt in your package.